# Android Gradient as progressDrawable

Tags: android, gradient, seekbar

Is there any progressDrawable generator or something that can help me doing this gradient (http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/DB/0E/15183348237ddb0e.png) ?

I tryed several things but without success I will be glad if there is something that can ease the process.

Comment: what several things did you try?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:centerColor="#00000000"
            android:centerX="1"
            android:endColor="#00000000"
            android:startColor="#00000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip
        android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="left" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:centerColor="#0000CC"
                android:centerX="0.75"
                android:endColor="#0000CC"
                android:startColor="#0000CC" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip
        android:clipOrientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="left" >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:centerColor="#0000CC"
                android:centerX="0.75"
                android:endColor="#0000CC"
                android:startColor="#0000CC" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```